Why google consent initialization takes too long to trigger?
I am trying to implement the consent mode that Google requires on a website and 2 scripts that read consent values, read them before the actual values are set. As a result in Google tag manager I get the error "A tag read consent state before a default was set". From the various testing procedures I have done, I concluded that even 'Consent Initialization' event that Google states is the first event that happens on the site, takes too much time to complete. Asychronous scripts that send data to analytics such as 'www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js' and 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?' finish execution before even 'Consent Initialization'. I tried to check if window.google_tag_data is defined but 'conversion.js' cannot be triggered after the page done loading. I also tried defer and async attributes.
I use 'gtm-templates-simo-ahava' template to implement the consent.
I cannot think of anything else of how to get rid of the 'A tag read consent state before a default was set' error. Anyone has any insight on this matter?
Update: The only Solution to this problem for now is to put anything related to tag manager and analytics into one gtm tag. This way google can control the order of the initializations. There is still the problem though that I don't know how to make a tag for conversion.js. I don't know what it does and even if needed.
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-xxxx');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

if (typeof window.google_tag_data !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('GTM initialized. Proceeding with other scripts.');
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxxx';
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'xxxxx');

    var google_conversion_id = xxxxx;
    var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
    var google_remarketing_only = true;

    const conversionScript = document.createElement('script');
    conversionScript.src = "https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js";
    conversionScript.async = true;  // Ensures script is executed after document parsing
    document.head.appendChild(conversionScript);
}



I genuinely do not understand your setup. Why do you deploy your tags in Javascript when at the same time running GTM? If you integrate your Google tags via GTM they will run as part of GTMs event queue and fire only after the init event. If you run them independently then they will not be controlled by GTM and fire whenever.

@EikePierstorff Yeah you are right that is what I understood too. Do you know how can you create tag for a custom script?

Nvm I found it. For anyone wondering, if you have custom scripts outside GTM like facebook pixel, you must create a custom HTML tag and paste it in there.
